# Basic Tivaware program Trouble

Tags: c++, c

I am a very new coder, and I'm trying to code a program that when SW1 is pressed on the Tivaware launch board, it lights the red LED and when I press both SW1 and SW2 the Blue LED is on. when I run the code shown below only the Red LED is on and there is no response from the board.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"


bool sw1_not_pressed,sw2_not_pressed,sw1_pressed,sw2_pressed;

int main(void){

    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_5|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3);
    GPIODirModeSet(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_DIR_MODE_IN);


    while(1)
    {
        sw1_not_pressed = GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4 );
        sw2_not_pressed = GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 );
        sw1_pressed = !sw1_not_pressed;
        sw2_pressed = !sw2_not_pressed;

        if(sw1_pressed)
        {
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_1);
        }
        else
        {
            if(sw2_pressed && sw1_pressed)
            {
                GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_2);
            }
            else
            {
                GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE,GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2,0x00 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am very grateful for any help given and thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: c and c++ are two different languages.  Only tag the relevant one.

Comment: Recheck your code logic. The `if(sw2_pressed && sw1_pressed)` body will never get executed, since that `if` is only reached when `!sw1_pressed` because of the `else` right above it..

Comment: Start by blinking the red LED. Then blue. Then use sw1 to control the red LED. Then sw2 to control blue. When you've proven all of the hardware, you can work on the real task.

Comment: As @dxiv noticed, when you write something like `if(sw1_pressed) { ... } else { ... }`, `else` here means "if sw1 is not pressed". So nested in it `if(sw2_pressed && sw1_pressed)` checks conditions, which could never be met, because it is nested into `else` block, which, as we mentioned, means "sw1 is NOT pressed"

Comment: And @user3386109 gave good advice - don't try to reach whole task at once - 1st decompose task at some (may be even "many") subtasks, which let you making little steps - step by step reach your whole task. Try decompose the way, every subtask give you visible relust - some checkable output (text at console or, as in your case - some LED behaviour).
Good luck! ;)

Comment: I just wanted to thank you guys for the support and tips you have given me for completing this code. I just want to inform you with your help I have successfully figured out how to get it to work.